# Node Js, calling exported function multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am building a application in electron, that deals with creating multiple task in the Renderer process, and each task performs the same process and has its own buttons, and when I click a button it sends a message to the main process that tells it to start the task, and on this event, it starts a function that I imported from another file, so If i have 10 task, and start all of them, it runs the function 10 times

```
index.js 

table.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.className == 'start') {
        ipcRenderer.send('start-task', taskId)
    } else if (event.target.className == 'stop') {
       ipcRenderer.send('stop-task', taskId)
    }
})
```

```
main.js 

const ccs = require('./ccs.js')

ipcMain.on('start-task', (event, taskid) => {
    ccs.CCScheckout(win, taskid)

})

ipcMain.on('stop-task', (event, taskid) => {
    ccs.stop(taskid)
})
```

```
performTask.js

let isStopped = false
let taskNum;

const checkout = async (win, taskId) => {
    taskNum = taskId
    //do asynchronous stuff, if isStopped is true, function returns; to stop the function 

}

const stop = (taskid) => { // if the task Id matches up, it stops the task 
    if (taskid == taskNum) {
        console.log(`task ${taskid}  stopped`)
        isStopped = true
    }
}

exports.performTask = checkout
exports.stop = stop
```

the problem is, when I want to have multiple task, and  I want to stop a task, I click the stop button, which sends an event to the main process that in return stops the task with the matching taskid, but instead of doing that, it will only stop the last task I started, so If task #4 was the last one i started, and I want to stop task #3, it will not stop task #3, but if I click task #4 it will stop all the task, for some reason the isStopped constant I define in performTask.js is being shared globally with all the other perFormTask functions

Comment: I don't understand--you have a single `isStopped` and `taskNum`, but multiple tasks, running async/concurrently? Wouldn't it make sense only to act on the task you care about?

Comment: A Stop button needs to be associated with a particular task some way so that when that event occurs, you know which task it refers to and you can pass that along to the function that's going to actually execute the stop.  It isn't clear from the code you've shared  where tasks are stored or how you'd associate a task with a particular stop button.  We'd have to see a bunch more context.